# How to use getReactively with find all helper in Angular Meteor?

Tags: angularjs, meteor, angular-meteor

I am working through Angular Meteor tutorial and got deprecation warning on

```
this.helpers({
   parties: () => {
      return Parties.find({});   //deprecation warning. Use getReactively             
   }
});
```

But I am not quite sure how to get all records reactively. I do not have any queries to say `return Parties.find({field: this.getReactively(query)})`.  I just want all records/everything similar to `Collection.find({}) or Parties.find({})` but without deprecation warning.

Comment: Common guys, please don't make me to switch to ReactJS.  I have already invested time & effort on Angular and Meteor! but still want to get the pattern right.

Comment: Ok Bala this is simple if you have searched it online...

Comment: This will help you a lot Bala. http://robertdickert.com/blog/2013/11/14/why-is-my-meteor-app-not-updating-reactively/   Dont switch to ReactJS.. It uses typescript which is not that good

Answer (score 0):

Im often use `parties: ()=> Parties.find()` and I'm has no error or deprecated warning. You maybe should try it.
Beside, sometime I need handle data fetch from query. Im used a temp variable for save data before handle it.
You can try (some code is pseudo code)

`parties: () {
           this.temp = Parties.find().fetch();
           if(this.temp) {
                 //handle data, adjust property like format string, format date....
                 return this.temp
           }
   }`

Its work, no deprecated, no error. You can try it.